# saving on intervals of time

Tags: timer

so basically my problem is that i want to save things on certain intervals of time. maybe save an image every 30s. the problem is i dont know how to do this. is there a function or something in php or html that can keep track of time so that i can save things every 30s or so. also since my file is a .tpl file, i am open to html, php and js options. i have the saving thing working properly, but right now i just want to save during certain intervals of time. my saving function is in js, so it would be nice if your answer had a certain way for me to call this js function.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions are pretty basic. Before implementing something, you should really do some tutorials or read a book. To call your save() every 30s in JavaScript just do:

```
setInterval(function () {
    save_to_server_function();
},30000);
```

This answer is also very basic and may not fit your needs. It depends on many things. You also dont want to save something that hasnt changed. Check for modifications and only save then.

And use more tags for your questions, f.e. javascript, http etc.